# Help figuring out what coupler to use to connect water supply line to corny keg

Tags: plumbing

I'm trying to connect this ball lock keg disconnect with an MFL fitting:

https://www.williamsbrewing.com/Home-Brewing-Equipment/Kegging-Equipment/Ball-Lock-Keg-Connectors/CMB-Beer-Ball-Lock-Threaded

To this water supply line with a 1/4" compression fitting:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-12-ft-Braided-Ice-Maker-Supply-Line-98260/307638941

I tried this:

https://www.lowes.com/pd/B-K-1-4-in-Threaded-Adapter-Fitting/1000504713

Which fits on the compression fitting, but is not a match for the ball lock disconnect, and this:

https://www.homebrewing.org/14-FFL-X-14-SS-Compression_p_5423.html

Which fits on the disconnect but is not a match for the supply line. These two couplers also do not fit together.

I'm unsure where I'm going wrong, I'm guessing that I'm not understanding the terminology correctly. Could someone tell me what I should be looking for or link to a product that would make this connection?

Comment: This seems like something which the members of the [Homebrewing stack](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/) might have already solved.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that existed, thanks! I don't think it's a common homebrewing thing though, this is for a seltzer water system. But if I don't have any luck here maybe I'll hit them up.

Comment: Take the 2 ends you do have to the store. Find fittings that will go into each of them. Find additional fittings that will make it work. Odds are good you won't find just _one_ that will go from A to B, you may have to go A to C to D to B, that's just the way it works. You'll probably want to start with the keg end, as that's probably the less common - find something that will adapt that to something more standard, then find a fitting (or two) that will adapt from there to your 1/4" compression.